# Binding nullable bit database column to CheckBox in GridView - crash when null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I'm trying to bind a nullable bit column, which at the moment is mostly null, but I need to somehow convert the null to a 'false' on runtime because it doesn't bind to a checkbox if it's null. But, I am currently unable to change the default value and update all records accordingly - is there a way to do this in runtime?

Comment: how are you pulling the data down?

Comment: SqlDataSource, sorry -forgot to say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your select to use `ISNULL(bit_column, 0)`. This way it will always have a value of false that you can bind to, even when the column has a null value in the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading it from a DataRow in a DataTable then you can do the following:

```
dataRow.Field<bool?>("ColumnName") ?? false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using a template field in the GridView like:

```
'<%# Eval("ColumnName") ?? false %>'
```